# Button image not showing in IE7 with bootstrap

Tags: image, button, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7

I have this problem in many places. Here is one:

```
<button type="button" name="remove_subnmc" class="btn"><img src="/static/img/delete.png"/></button>
```

The button simply appears as empty in IE7. It looks fine in all other browsers.

Without the class="btn" it looks even worse.

I'm using Django, but I don't think that's relevant so I haven't tagged it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the width of the button manually can fix this, even if you pick the exact width the button was already displayed at.

Interestingly, setting a min-width of at least the image size, on either the image or the button, while not changing the button at all, will fix this as well. Any smaller than that and the image is shrunken accordingly. In this case all of my buttons have 16px images and all of my buttons are at least this wide, so a general min-width applied to all of my buttons in IE7 is an acceptable solution.

However, if I wanted to add a wider button image in some cases I would need to make specific exceptions for that just for IE7, so if anyone knows a more elegant solution I would love to hear it.